# Burmese language is shown as "boxes" in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have observed that Burmese language is shown as "boxes" are record level in SQL server 2012.  Both the fields shown in the screenshot are *nvarchar* type with more than the required length.Is this expected ? If so why.

[image: Attached is the screen shot for your reference]

Comment: This sounds like an encoding problem.  What is the effective encoding which would apply to each column?

Comment: Perhaps the font does not support these characters.  You may have to change the font.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing it in nvarchar then it is OK,
You can test it by copy and paste one of the row data into Google Translate where Burma language is selected as source, if you see the text in Burma language characters, then it is OK
It is related with the editor

Answer (score 0):

You have to install correct Burmese font Zawgyi or Myanmar-1.

[image]